# prestashop 1.7 manually get hook name

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

how do I get the hook name of the hook a module is using?
I need it to use in a conditional statement e.g. in my custom tpl

```
{if hook_name = 'leftDisplay'}
 do_this_on_left_display
{else if}
 do_this_on_diff_display
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the hook as a smarty variable from the hook method to the tpl. For example in PHP:

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
{
    $smarty->assign(
        array(
            'hook_name' => 'leftDisplay'
        )
    );
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'yourtplfile.tpl');
}
```

Then you can access it in the tpl like this:

```
{if $hook_name == 'leftDisplay'}
    do_this_on_left_display
{else if $hook_name == 'otherHookName'}
    do_this_on_diff_display
{else}
    {*Unknown hook*}
{/if}
```